# Jira - How To Make PHP CURL API Calls Using Jira Access Token

Tags: oauth, jira

I need to use the Jira rest API to create an issue using the user's access token, but I keep getting 403 response.

I have researched the API documentation extensively and a lot on Stack Overflow, but no success yet.

Although most of the research I have done mentioned that you should create an API token, this will not work for me since all the users connect with my Jira application using Oauth and then I get the user's access tokens when they grant access.

The Jira documentation shows that you can use the user's access token to make API calls. Please see the link and Excerpt from the link.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/

Excerpt from the link mentioned above:
**Step 4: Make a request**

"**An access token is all that we need to make an authenticated request to
the Jira REST API using OAuth**. Requests are made as the user who authorized
the initial request token. The access token will persist for 5 years,
unless it is revoked."

Would someone please be able to assist me?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I know I am answering my own question, but Jira support provided the correct documentation links for Oauth if someone might be interested.

Oauth 2.0 Docs:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/

Regards
Shaun